# Routing to client and server from single Nginx server config

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm trying to use a single Nginx server config to route requests either to the client or a micro service behind it:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  # My client.
  location /app/ {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
  }

  # My server.
  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://server:8080;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

The idea is that the client would call `<base>/api/<some-rest-url>` to make calls to the micro service. These calls would then be routed by nginx to the service.

With the given setup I see the following result:

- Service is available at /api/
- Client is not available at /app/ (404 not found)

I assume this is an issue with the way the locations are defined, but can't figure out how to solve the issue.

Note: I don't want the service to be available on a different port on nginx, it should be on the same port, but on a different route (e.g. in this case /api/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution to my problem. Instead of using `/app/` for my client, I know use `/` for my client and just redirect the service requests to `/api/`. The trailing slash after the server url in the `proxy_pass` means that the `/api/` path is not duplicated:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
  }

  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://server:8080/; # Important trailing slash!
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't add `$args` in the `try_files`. It means that for query `GET /something?arg=value` HTTP request, nginx would try to open file in path: `/somethingarg=value`.

Answer (score 0):

nginx appends the URI path to end of path in `root` when looking up the file.

In your case, a request to `http://example.com/app/index.html` makes nginx look up the file in `/usr/share/nginx/html/app/index.html`.

Using `alias` instead of `root` prevents nginx from appending the URI path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This config causes a 403 for me when accessing /app/: `*1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html" is forbidden`. Is there something else that needs to be changed?